# Capitalizing in R with Exceptions

Tags: r

How can you capitalize data on R except add boundaries?

For example:

Given a list of cities and states in the form: "NEW YORK, NY"
It needs to be changed to: "New York, NY"

The str_to_title function changes it to "New York, Ny".

Patterns:
WASHINGTON, DC
AMHERST, MA
HANOVER, NH
DAVIDSON, NC
BRUNSWICK, ME
GREENVILLE, SC
PORTLAND, OR
LOUISVILLE, KY

They should all be in the form: Amherst, MA or Brunswick, ME

Comment: I added them to the original post.

Comment: Can you check my solution below. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a negative regex lookaround to match the upper case letters that are not succeeding the `,` and space , capture as a group (`(...)`), in the replacement specify the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`, `\\2`) while converting the second group to lower (`\\L`)

```
gsub("(?<!, )([A-Z])([A-Z]+)\\b", "\\1\\L\\2", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "New York, NY"   "Washington, DC" "Amherst, MA"    "Hanover, NH" 
#[5]  "Davidson, NC"   "Brunswick, ME" 
#[7] "Greenville, SC" "Portland, OR"   "Louisville, KY"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("NEW YORK, NY", "WASHINGTON, DC", "AMHERST, MA", "HANOVER, NH", 
  "DAVIDSON, NC", "BRUNSWICK, ME", "GREENVILLE, SC", "PORTLAND, OR", 
 "LOUISVILLE, KY")
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Can you explain the gsub command along with the arguments associated? I'm not entirely sure why this works, but it does.